# Can't import .obj

Tags: import

I know how to import obj normally. how ever, if you direct your attention to the attached image you will see that the option to import an Obj is not there. I only have Collada and Alembic as an option to import. When I start with a fresh Blender project, no problem I can import the obj, but i want to do it in the file I'm working on. What the hell is going on, can someone please give me advice about this.

[image]

Comment: Have tried to open the file through *File > Open* with the *Load UI* option unchecked?

Comment: i had to remove the addon and add it back again

Answer (score 1):

You can try loading the factory settings under the *File* menu.

Also you can open a new Blender file then import the object on that new file then copy and paste the imported object.

Answer (score 1):

Alejandro Nevárez Lucio is probably right on in his answer.

More specifically, in the Preferences, under "Add-ons", make sure that "Import-Export: Wavefront OBJ Format" is checked. See image.
[image]